# About the views start with v$ in oracle

Tags: oracle

I notice that many views, esp. the data dictionary views, start with v$ in oracle, is there some differences than other views in oracle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are called dynamic performance views which are maintained by oracle server.
These views provide data on internal disk structures and memory structures. These views can be selected from, but never updated or altered by the user.

You can check more details at this link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_1001.htm#i1398692